# The scroll event of the weex scroller control conflicts with the touch event of the child control

Tags: vue.js, touch, scroller, weex

This is a question about Weex development with Vue.

Under a `scroller` component, there are a number of nested `div` child components. In the `div`, the gestures `touchstart`, `touchend`, and `touchcancel` are added.

The events handle the press and release effects, but they make the scroller drag event non-functional. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to post questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add touch effects to view, you can use pseudo class:

```html
<style scoped>
  .logo {
    width: 360px;
    height: 82px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .logo:active {
    width: 180px;
    height: 82px;
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>
```

ref: http://weex.apache.org/references/common-style.html#Pseudo-class-v0-9-5